# Windows: Read another process' memory directly

Tags: c++, windows, performance, memory

I need to scan another process' memory in Windows. The ReadProcessMemory function does it just fine but it copies each time memory from the target process to one of my buffers.. is there any way to access another process' memory without copying it to my process' memory every time? If there were I could use pointers to access the other process' memory

Comment: If you could access it directly, you could modify it directly. That's a major security risk, so I doubt it's possible.

Comment: You could [inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) your scanning code into the other process and use inter-process communication to pass the results of the scan to the controlling process.

Comment: @StoryTeller: not necessarily. It could be mapped into your virtual address space for read-only, just like you can do with file-mapping. Implementable in principle, though I doubt there is an API for this.

Comment: Does the ReadProcessMemory add overhead due to the memory copy process?

Comment: @ybungalobill that's exactly what I was thinking of, is there anything like that?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: I suspect that copying memory around always adds overhead.

Comment: Let's take a step back. What is the problem where you think scanning another process's memory is the solution? You should be using whatever interfaces are exposed by the application; anything else is just an unsupported hack.

Comment: I need to act like a debugger and read the debugged process' memory. I don't want to copy-back-and-forth memory every time

Comment: Your only choices are to use ReadProcessMemory() or to inject code into the other process. Both will cause memory copying. ReadProcessMemory() does the copying implicitly; your injected code will need to copy something out when it alerts another process that it has found what it has been looking for.

Comment: Debuggers use ReadProcessMemory(). They minimize the amount of memory they need to read; they only read what they're going to display (in a memory view window or a watch window.)

Comment: @MikeB I put that into another question because it's a different one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130154/how-do-debuggers-work-with-readprocessmemory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debuggers use `ReadProcessMemory`, so if you're implementing something that functions like a debugger, that's the right way to do it.

If you're implementing something else, you're probably heading into the weeds and you should give us a higher-level view of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I didn't know that debuggers use ReadProcessMemory, do they read small chunks of memory at a time or do they read all the process' memory into one buffer?

Comment: They read only what they need. Rarely does a debugger need to access the entire process's memory all at once.