# How do debuggers work with ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory

It's my understanding that debuggers use ReadProcessMemory (in a Windows environment) to read another process' memory.. what am I wondering is: ReadProcessMemory reads another process' memory to a buffer so it causes overhead. Do debuggers read small chunks of memory or do they read the entire process' memory in one shot?

Comment: Does not look answerable to me. There are plenty of different debuggers and they free to do whatever works for each particular case. Likely most would read in chunks if needed at all... Especially in x64 :) also one can imagine reading whole 16/32 bit process space into large 32/64 bit process to analyze.

Comment: I have never written a debugger, but if I did..  If the user asks for a stack back trace, it might make sense to read the stack (about 1 MB) of that thread.  If you user wants to print a variable, read the memory for just that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API does not guarantee atomic read. Eventually it copies data (as opposed to providing access to original bytes through address mapping), and if the debuggee is still running it might be altering the memory in question while the API call is in progress.